# How to rewrite .htaccess rule to URL minus one character?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

A Newsletter was send with a token generated login URL inside. Accidentally a closing square bracket ] was placed as the URL's last character and the login links now doesn't work. How to redirect any URL with a closing square bracket to the same URL without the square bracket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use mod_alias and the `RedirectMatch` directive or mod_rewrite and the `RewriteRule` directive. If you already are using mod_rewrite elsewhere, it may be more prudent to stick with mod_rewrite, otherwise it doesn't matter:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)\]$ /$1
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\]$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: The RewriteRule is fine. I think it's the escaped slash that did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+?)]$ /$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```